# How to use Apache's mod_rewrite to change the HTTP version in a request?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have an old system sending a POST to an old version of Apache(2.4.9) that is not sending the HTTP version.  The old system has no issue but I want to update Apache to the latest.  When I do, Apache logs an error that only a GET is valid with HTTP/0.9.  I tried writing a mod_rewrite to append a version to the request but I still get the errors.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/0\.9$  
RewriteRule (.*) "$1 HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: AFAIK http protocol version 0.9 also doesn’t send a `Host:` so when you only adjust the protocol version you still don’t get a valid http/1.1 request  where that header is mandatory

Comment: Also, there's no version (`HTTP/0.9`) in the request, as it is just `GET /path`.

Comment: What makes you believe you *can* use mod_rewrite for this purpose?

Comment: Well, you can fail requests for certain HTTP versions.

Comment: I understand that HTTP/0.9 is GET only.  However, I have a system not under my control that is sending the following request:

POST http://localhost/InsertLine3.php?Date='2023-04-03'&Time='12:11:49'&Line=3&Model='96795400600'&Serial='040323C014086'&UPC='0193028712946'&Returnable='N63-0082422'&Bypass=''&QAHold=''&PASS='Y'

It's working on an older version of Apache as stated above and I want to upgrade Apache.  If anyone has a better idea of how to handle it, I would appreciate the advice.